# Toggling sync and async behavior in .NET web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I've been asked to implement something like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(bool sync)
{
    if(sync)
    {
        ...sync behavior
    } else
    {
        ...async behavior
    }
}
```

Now, I understand the basics of sync/async behavior and threading, and am worried about things that might go wrong (async code running synchronously, thread-blocking,returning an arbitrary Task to match the method signature being generally sloppy, etc...), but not enough to say for certain that this code is a bad idea. So, my question: Is this always bad practice, or are there cases where it can be okay?

Comment: Much better to have 2 distinct methods for various reasons. If nothing else, the naming convention of an async method is usually to add the `Async` suffix and `GetAsync(sync: false)` just looks nasty. Also when you go through the non-sync path, there's no task to await on. Meh, feels horrible.

Comment: This was my exact answer and reaction, so thanks! My professional situation complicates it a bit, because I'm the only API dev on a mobile team (and a junior), and kind of need to be able to tell my senior team leads, definitively enough, "No, this will not work.", and in particular, why.

Comment: Are there actually sync and async variations to how this method works, or are you being forced into faking one or the other (e.g. via `Task.Run` or `.Wait` or `.Result` calls)? In most circumstances, there's only one or the other and it should push it's "syncness" or "asyncness" higher up the call stack than here.

Comment: The two code paths are almost identical. One awaits a Task and returns the result, one fires off the task and returns a 200.

Comment: While the [bool argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) is appropriate in some situations, I cannot think of why you would *ever* want to have the boolean argument sourced from a query parameter.

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen Cleary. Also, a little gushy, I know, but an honor to hear from the writer of the blog I immediately went to when these questions arose. As for the "why", my team lead would like to give the user the option to either fire and forget, or wait for a success/failure result for the Task. Which I think is reasonable; I 'm just worried about safety, and would prefer separate endpoints or controllers, which I know are safe.

Comment: @dylanthelion: [`async` does not cause "fire and forget" behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). The client *cannot tell the difference* between sync and async action methods. And the client can call any API in a synchronous, asynchronous, or fire-and-forget fashion, regardless of the API's implementation.

Comment: Interesting. I just wanted to say thanks, because I'm about halfway through this post, and there's quite a bit I didn't know (mostly surrounding how await seems to be decoupled from the request, and informed by worker threads, if I get that right, and scalability), and I'll be busy with this for a while. So, yeah, thanks for taking the time to help out a junior dev. It can sometimes be really tough, when nobody on the team is sure of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async methods will run synchronously until they reach an `await`. If the `await` is waiting for a result, the control is given back.

So there is nothing wrong with your code, as long as the async path uses an await.

But it is important to note, that is an async method has not to wait for any long running operation, it will be executed synchronously! So even if you use an await, there is no guarantee that the control is given back.

Comment: The await Task does take anywhere from several to 10+ seconds. But you're saying that as long as something is awaited in the async path, I'm not introducing any danger or instability that would be averted by using two different methods?

Comment: In short: yes. One could say this is to some extend bad practice. Because the caller will not know how the method will react. But technically you are completely safe.